# Converting colour image to grey scale (Matlab)

Tags: matlab

I'm having some trouble converting a tif image into grey scale so I can have a look at the pixel values. I first used the code

```
im = imread('etc.');
im = rgb2gray(im);
imshow(im)
```

but this doesn't display grey scale values - it shows an RGB colour map. I've also tried loading the colour map to then convert the map

```
[im,map] = imread('etc.');
```

but the map is empty. Any pointers appreciated - I couldn't see anything useful in the Matlab help.

Edit: imshow results [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will not be a colour map in the file if it's a rgb image - only if it's an indexed image.

`imshow` uses a default colour map (`jet`).  If you want a greyscale map, you have to deliberately set `colormap gray`.

```
im = rgb2gray(imread('filename'));
imshow(im)
colormap gray
```

Comment: I've added the results of imshow. Whilst it does now seem to be a grayscale value, it seems to be normalised between 0-1. Any way to change this to 0-255?

Comment: If your image is of class `uint8` and scaled between 0 and 255, `impixelinfo` should show you integers.  If it doesn't, the issue is that your original file is 0 to 1 scaled (and probably `double`).

Comment: I can't use impixelinfo - I get an error every time. 

Error using impixelinfo>parseInputs (line 172)
H is an invalid graphics handle.

Error in impixelinfo (line 62)
[h,parent] = parseInputs(varargin{:});

Do you know how I would fix the issue if the latter is the case?

Comment: How are you calling it? If you show the image with `imshow` and then afterwards call `impixelinfo` with no inputs, it should automatically associate itself with the current figure.  To pass in a handle directly you would do something like `h = imshow(im); impixelinfo(h)`.  There should be more examples in the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think with the .tif format you have to use the command

```
[X,map] = imread('imagename.tif')
newmap = rgb2gray(map)
imshow(X,newmap)
```

Link to online Matlab help where's this exact example: [RGB to gray](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2gray.html)

Comment: Won't be much help if the `map` is empty (as in this case).